# Salesforce Licensing for developing webservice

Tags: developer

I am developing a webservice, which will fetch data from 3rd party application and show it in Salesforce application. Do I need to buy developer license to make my webservice available to be used by any user of Salesforce. Also, will i have to pay any licensing fee for publishing my webservice through SalesForce.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a [free developer edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup), good for as long as you need to use it. If you will be publishing your web service code for free, there's no security review cost to be published on the AppExchange. If you plan on charging for it, *and* want to be published on the AppExchange, you need to [become a partner](https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/). The initial security review is $2,700 (renewals are cheaper), as well as agreeing to pay a small portion of the license fees you collect.